# How to render multiple models from useFBX? @react-three/drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to display multiple components using `useFBX` in `@react-three/drei`. Though I am calling the function twice I am getting only one component inside the scene.

I have the following code to render a tree inside the scene

```
import { useBox } from "@react-three/cannon";
import { useFBX } from "@react-three/drei";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const Trees = (props) => {
  const [ref] = useBox(() => ({
    mass: 1,
    type: "Static",
    ...props,
  }));
  let fbx = useFBX(props.fbx);
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <mesh ref={ref} scale={props.scale} position={props.position}>
        <primitive object={fbx} dispose={null} />
      </mesh>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Trees;
```

And I am calling the function in another file

```
    import React from "react";
    import Trees from "./Trees";
    
    const TreeDisplay = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <Trees
            fbx="/FBX/Tree1.fbx"
            position={[10, 0, 20]}
            scale={[0.01, 0.01, 0.01]}
          />
          <Trees
            fbx="/FBX/Tree1.fbx"
            position={[20, 0, 0]}
            scale={[0.01, 0.01, 0.01]}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
   export default TreeDisplay;
```

The above function has to add two trees inside the scene in the defined position, but I am getting only one tree.

Comment: thats because you're using primitive which simply drops the root object into the scene. in threejs you can have the same object in two places unless you use instancing. with three-fiber you dont have to use the root object like that, you can express the graph declaratively, see: https://codesandbox.io/s/re-using-gltfs-dix1y

gltfjsx automates that. but even for fbx you could build it manually, or use the useGraph which gives you node/material collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the fbx, cloning the fbx model completes the job.

```
import { useBox } from "@react-three/cannon";
import { Loader, useFBX } from "@react-three/drei";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const Trees = (props) => {
  const [ref] = useBox(() => ({
    mass: 1,
    type: "Static",
    ...props,
  }));
  let fbx = useFBX(props.fbx);
  //Add this line
  let fbxClone = fbx.clone();
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <mesh ref={ref} scale={props.scale} material-reflectivity={1}>
        //pass the cloned object
        <primitive object={fbxClone} dispose={null} />
      </mesh>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Trees;
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript when you use an object you use it's direct reference, so you need to make a copy of that object :

```
let fbx = useFBX(props.fbx);
let fbxClone = {...fbx};
```

There is also an object3D.clone() function that might be useful in this case :

```
let fbxClone = fbx.clone();
```

Other than that you might want to use the javascript .map function which if you get an array of objects allows you to make an array of components out of it.

```
let mytrees  = [];
for(let i = 0;i<1000; i++)
   mytrees.push(fbx.clone());

return (<>{mytrees.map((tree)=>{return <instancedMesh material={tree.material} 
                                        geometry={tree.geometry} />})}</>)
```

Here is a complete code of that(with a gltfloader, but it should work the same way with fbx ) :

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useMemo, Suspense, useEffect, memo } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader, extend, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader"
import * as THREE from 'three'

const Trees = memo((props) => {
    let listOfRefs = [];
    const tempObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    let treeTypes = ["three_1"];
    let loadedTrees = [];
    let trees = [];

    for(let cur of treeTypes)
    {
        loadedTrees.push(Object.values(useLoader(GLTFLoader, cur+'.glb',(loader) => {
          const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
          dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("/draco-gltf/");
          loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
        }).nodes).filter(m=>{return (m instanceof THREE.Mesh)})
        .map(m=>{return (<instancedMesh material={m.material} 
                                        geometry={m.geometry} 
                                        key={cur+""+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)} 
                                        count={props.amount}
                                        ref={(()=>{
                                                listOfRefs.push(useRef()); 
                                                return listOfRefs[listOfRefs.length-1];
                                                })()}
                                        args={[null,null,props.amount]} />)}));
                                        
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (listOfRefs.length < 1) return;
        let i = 0;
        for(let c = 0;c<props.amount;c++)
        {
            let currentPosition = [ Math.round(Math.random())?(Math.random()*props.halfSize):-(Math.random()*props.halfSize),
                                    13.75 , 
                                    Math.round(Math.random())?(Math.random()*props.halfSize):-(Math.random()*props.halfSize)];
            let currentRotation = [0,(Math.round(Math.random())*Math.PI/2),0]
            for(let curRef of listOfRefs) {
                const id = i++;
                tempObject.position.set(currentPosition[0],currentPosition[1],currentPosition[2])
                tempObject.rotation.set(currentRotation[0],currentRotation[1],currentRotation[2]);
                tempObject.updateMatrix();
                curRef.current.setMatrixAt(id, tempObject.matrix);
            }
        }
        for(let curRef of listOfRefs)
            curRef.current.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
        
    })
   return (
        <group>
            {loadedTrees[Math.floor(Math.random()*loadedTrees.length)]}
        </group>
   );
})
export default Trees;
```

Another suggestion would be to use instancedMesh as proposed here :
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=instanced#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh
it exists as à react-three-fiber component

`<instancedMesh />`

Comment: Cloning it only, did the work. `let fbxClone = fbx.clone();` 
Passing this into the primitive completes the job.
`<primitive object={fbxClone} dispose={null} />`. Been struggling with this for days, Thanks.